# Unknown column in 'where clause' while there`s no 'where clause' and the column isn`t mentioned in the query

Tags: mysql-error-1054

I`m new in SQL and now straggling with an error 1054 Unknown column in 'where clause' in MySQL.

1. There`s a simple table 'customer_orders' with 3 columns 'order_id', 'staff_id' and 'order_total'
2. I needed to insert a line. My query was
   INSERT INTO customer_orders VALUES (25,1,10.50);
3. First that worked, then I realized a need to delete the row and insert with a slight change
4. Now it throws the error 'Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'order_id' in 'where clause''
   There`s no such column in the query and the column isn`t mentioned.
   I renamed the column into 'order_id_new' and explicitly specified the column names in the INSERT statement - the same error.

INSERT INTO customer_orders (order_id_new, staff_id, order_total) VALUES
(23,1,11.43);

When I created a copy of the table the same worked fine.

Any ideas what is wrong with the table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did this work without `VALUES`? `INSERT INTO customer_orders (25,1,10.50);`

Comment: Where did you use the "WHERE" clause...no pun intended.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out there was a Trigger which conflicted with the query. Strange that the error doesn`t refer to the trigger in any way. Once I fixed the trigger the query worked.